# Postgresql WAL-E - Replication falling behind + can't catch up

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-s3

Does anyone know how I can have my replications process the WAL segments faster while using WAL-E?  https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e

I have one master that leverages WAL-E to upload to S3, and I have 6 replications (hot_standby) that pull information down from S3 but some of them are falling behind.

Interestingly enough the 2 replication servers in NYC generally don't fall behind, but the other 4 (SF, Atlanta) are falling behind (2000 seconds+) and don't seem to be catching up.

Does anyone have any advice/suggestions on how I can fix this?

I even slowed down the number of inserts into the master, but they're still falling behind.

Comment: You need to examine the server logs on the replicas that are falling behind. Please edit the question to include relevant log excerpts. Comment here when you've made the edit so I see the change.

Comment: Log files wouldn't be relevant.  Basically wal segments are fetched from S3 and processed every 3 seconds on the replica.

Comment: Including the slow/behind replicas? What rate is WAL being generated at on the master? Are they connected as streaming replicas, or only pulling WAL files? If they're not connected as streaming replicas with WAL archives as fallback, why not? How long does it take to download a WAL segment to the replica? How long to replay it? i.e. is it transfer speed from S3 that's an issue, or replay speed on the replica?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you're using log shipping using S3 as common storage. You should use streaming replication instead. This way your slaves should not fall behind more than a few seconds.

But it may generate bandwidth costs - $0.01 per GB as I remember. You can use cascading replication to pay for this bandwith only once for several servers.

You can also use log shipping to S3 for disaster recovery purposes.

I suppose that maybe S3 is replicating data between availability zones and what you see is a delay of this replication.

Comment: I disagree that you should use streaming replication *or* WAL shipping; even with streaming replication, you want WAL shipping as a backup in case of lasting connection loss or another reason causing the standby to lag far enough behind that the master no longer retains old enough WAL. This is the advice in the manual, too.

Comment: I believe we are actually using both. If a replication falls behind it grabs the WAL segments and processes them, otherwise it just connects via streaming.

Comment: So I believe your streaming replication isn't working. I don't think it is possible for working streaming replication to be constantly more that a couple of seconds behind. Either it will eventually catch up or it will fall back more and more when there's insufficient network or storage bandwidth.

Comment: @CraigRinger with replication slots you can solve the problem of the master deleting unreplicated WAL